# If $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ are relatively prime integers, find the $\text{gcd}$ of $2a+(1+2a)(a^2-b^2)$ and $2a(a^2+2a-b^2)$.

Tags: number-theory

I have found that $\text{gcd}((a²-b²),2a)=1$ and $\text{gcd}((a²-b²+2a),2a)=1$.By using the fact that $\text{gcd}(a,b)=\text{gcd}(a,b+ax)$ I tried and couldn't find the answer

Comment: Once you know $\gcd(2a, a^2 + 2a - b^2) = 1$ then $\gcd(x, 2a(a^2 + 2a - b^2)) = \gcd(x, 2a) \gcd(x, a^2 + 2a - b^2)$ for any $x$.

Comment: Please can you expand your answer till the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ then $\gcd(xy, z) = \gcd(x, z) \gcd(y, z)$. In this case, let $x = 2a$, $y = a^2 + 2a - b^2$ and $z = 2a + (1+2a)(a^2-b^2) = x + (1 + x)(y - x) = x + y - x + xy - x^2$ and your problem is to compute $\gcd(xy, z)$ which can be obtained by multiplying $\gcd(x, z)$ and $\gcd(y, z)$ together since you already know that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$. We have
$$\gcd(x, z) = \gcd(2a + (1+2a)(a^2-b^2), 2a) = \gcd((1+2a)(a^2-b^2), 2a) =  \gcd(a^2-b^2 , 2a) = 1$$
and
$$\gcd(y, z) = \gcd(2a + (1+2a)(a^2-b^2), a^2 + 2a - b^2) = \gcd(2a + (1+2a)(a^2-b^2+2a) - (1 + 2a)2a, a^2 + 2a - b^2) = \gcd(2a - (1 + 2a)2a, a^2 + 2a - b^2) = \gcd(-4a^2, a^2 + 2a - b^2) = 1$$
so the answer is $1 \times 1 = 1$. We can do it abstractly by noting that $$z = x + (1 + x)(y - x) = x + y - x + xy - x^2 = y + xy - x^2$$
as well:
$$\gcd(x, z) = \gcd(x, y + xy - x^2) = \gcd(x, y) = 1$$
and
$$\gcd(y, z) = \gcd(y, y + xy - x^2) = \gcd(y, -x^2) = 1.$$

Comment: How did you at last say that gcd is 1??

Comment: What will be the gcd if it is asked for 2a+(1+2a)(a²-b²) and                         2a(a²+2a-b²)(a²-b²)

Comment: See my updated answer. The answer is still 1.

Comment: Extremely grateful